# 'overflow' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use clipBehavior instead

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need an overflowed widget using clip behavior and I have no idea how to do that?

```
 child: Row(
    children: [
        Stack(
            children: [],
        overflow: Overflow.clip,
                                  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use `clipBehavior` like this:

```dart
Stack(
  clipBehavior: Clip.none, // This is what you need. 
  children: [],
)
```

Comment: what if I want overflow.visible?

Comment: @AnAndroid This is exactly what `Clip.none` is doing.